# Implementing Custom scrollball inside fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have a fancybox inside which i have a section for image, in that section i want a scroll bar which i have, but i want to use anti scroll(custom scrollbar)for this.

I found one at https://github.com/Automattic/antiscroll
but how can make this function for antiscroll to execute once the fancybox is completely loaded?

I found solution using ajax, is there any other way of doing it other than ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Call you Tiny scroll bar or antitiny scroll bar function with a delay,

For eg: setTimeoutfunction(){tinyscrollbar();},2000);